# javascript: how to parse a date string

Tags: javascript, jquery

The format is:
MMDDHHMM

I want to take month, day, hour, minute individually, how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var dateString = '13011948';
```

The length of the text is fixed and always at the same position. Then you can just use `substr` to cut them into parts and use `parseInt` to convert them to number.

```
var month = parseInt(dateString.substr(0, 2), 10),
      day = parseInt(dateString.substr(2, 2), 10),
     hour = parseInt(dateString.substr(4, 2), 10),
   minute = parseInt(dateString.substr(6, 2), 10);
```

Or instead, put it in a single date object.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMonth   (parseInt(dateString.substr(0, 2), 10) - 1);
date.setDate    (parseInt(dateString.substr(2, 2), 10));
date.setHours   (parseInt(dateString.substr(4, 2), 10));
date.setMinutes (parseInt(dateString.substr(6, 2), 10));
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

The moment.js library found [here](http://momentjs.com/) looks amazing for this!

**END EDIT**

this should help...[working with Dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)

Comment: wow, elated is still running!! i used to go there for free website templates before the turn of the millenium (and long before i was a web dev)! cheers for the walk down memory lane :-)

Comment: lol I had never heard of it. popped up in google when I searched. Looks like a good resource for this though...

Comment: Answers of "use library X" should be comments, they aren't answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're guaranteed that it's always going to be in MMDDHHMM format, you could parse it with a simple regex.

```
var d = "01121201";
var m = /([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/.exec(d);

console.log(m);
```

which would output

```
["01121201", "01", "12", "12", "01"]
```

But using the actual date functions is better if possible.

You could do something like the following to take the result of the regex match above to create a true Javascript Date object:

```
//The year will default to the current year
var realDate = new Date();
realDate.setMonth(m[1]);
realDate.setDate(m[2]);
realDate.setHours(m[3]);
realDate.setMinutes(m[4]);
```

Comment: You have an impressive beard!

Comment: You should see it now!  It's short in that picture :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several method in javascript Date object which would get you those parameters

```
var curdate = new Date(); 
var mday = curdate.getDate();        //returns day of month
var month = curdate.getMonth();      //returns month 0-11
var hours = curdate.getHours();      //returns hours 0-23
var minutes = curdate.getMinutes();  //returns minutes 0-59
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

If you do not have date object you can parse it using

```
var curdate = Date.parse("Jan 1, 2010");
```

To parse date to your specific format refer [this](http://www.xaprb.com/articles/javascript-date-parsing-demo.html)

Comment: Are you sure the second example is correct? Date.parseDate() doesn't seem to exist for me and the Date.parse() function which takes a single argument in IETF format.